# How do I remove a document with node-mongodb-native driver?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

The operation returns saying `deleted: 0`

```
const res = await ctx.db.collection(this.col).removeOne({ _id: ctx.params.id });
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here. GET requests by the `{ _id: <id> }` seem to work fine.

`ctx.params.id` is defined and is the same as the ObjectId in the database.

According to this doc you can do `collection.removeOne()` (see example 2) https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Collection.html#remove

```
// Remove all the document
collection.removeOne({a:1}, {w:1}, function(err, r) {
  test.equal(null, err);
  test.equal(1, r.result.n);
  db.close();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try casting `ctx.params.id` to [`ObjectId`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/), which is how mongodb stores identifiers internally.

```
import { ObjectId } from 'mongodb'

id = ObjectId(ctx.params.id)
```

Comment: Why would I have to do that when I don't anywhere else I use ids?

Comment: @chovy I'm actually not sure, but you can try. Your code above looks alright to me.

Comment: That works! man, why on this method but not any other? weird.

Comment: @chovy I'd love to give you an answer to this, but I don't know really. I know that mongoose does this by itself, not sure why mongodb does not (and specially why it doesn't just in the deleteOne).

Comment: is it good practice to always do this? I don't seem to have any issues with `.find({ _id: ctx.params.id })`

Comment: @chovy considering this case, I would. You are avoiding false positives. Either way, a redundant ObjectId won't hurt. MongoDB requires ObjectId's anyway under the hood (and will always return you ObjectIDs on find)